# How to Convert Sql to Linq with Distinct(id)

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, distinct

***select count(distinct  LicencePlate) from MT_Vehicle where IsDeleted=0 and CreatedBy = 1***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var count = MT_Vehicle.Where(x => x.IsDeleted==0 && x.CreatedBy == 1)
                      .Select(x => x.LicencePlate)
                      .Distinct()
                      .Count();
```

Comment: So? What would you expect instead?

Comment: I want to show the total vehicle count without duplicates based on the license plate and not shown deleted vehicles

Comment: You do realize that I don't have magic powers, right? For all I know, your table could be *empty*. So based on your description, you should delete the part that filters on "CreatedBy".

Answer (score 0):

You can write that as:

```
var count = db.MT_Vehicle
    .Where( v => v.IsDeleted == 0 && v.CreatedBy == 1 )
    .Select(v => v.LicencePlate)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```